# Sufficient conditions for joint normality?

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose I have $n$ random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ such that $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and the increments $X_i - X_{i-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,s)$ are independent. Are these conditions sufficient to conclude the vector $\textbf{X} = (X_1,...,X_n)$ is a multivariate Gaussian? If so, what is the covariance matrix?

Comment: This isn't what "sufficiency" usually refers to in statistics, so you might want to reword the question title a little, but it is a good question.

Comment: Oops! My ignorance is showing. Do you have a suggestion for rewording the title?

Comment: How about "Sufficient condition for joint normality?"

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following this, you are assuming the collection $\{X_i - X_{i-1}\}$ are iid $\mathcal N(0, s)$? Is $X_1$ considered independent of these?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of Brownian motion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions (plus the assumption that the first value is independent of all the increments) amount to assuming that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \sim \text{Normal}_n(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma})$, where

1. $\mathbf{A} = 
   \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 
   \end{array}\right]$
2. $\mathbf{x} = 
   \left[\begin{array}{c} 
   x_1 \\ 
   x_2 \\ 
   \vdots \\ 
   x_n 
   \end{array}\right]$
3. $\mathbf{\Sigma} = \text{diag}(1,s,\ldots,s)$

This means 
$$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \sim \text{Normal}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{A}^{-1})^T ),
$$
where $\mathbf{A}^{-1} = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Nice and clean!